# Webpack v4, ejected create-react-app. How to configure autoprefixer?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, postcss, autoprefixer

I'm in a pickle.
I have used a create-react-app (v2), ejected it, and build my project structure along the lines of

```
projectDir > src > pages > page > page.js || page.css
```

and I have multiple pages.

I've been trying to configure webpack with postcss and autoprefixer, but there is nothing remotely resembling what I have for my `webpack.config.dev.js`. Here is the part of my webpack that has the postcss with autoprefixer:

```
const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
  const loaders = [
    require.resolve('style-loader'),
    {
      loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
      options: cssOptions,
    },
    {
      // Options for PostCSS as we reference these options twice
      // Adds vendor prefixing based on your specified browser support in
      // package.json
      loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
      options: {
        // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
        // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2677
        ident: 'postcss',
        plugins: () => [
          require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
          require('postcss-preset-env')({
            autoprefixer: {
              flexbox: 'no-2009',
            },
            stage: 3,
          }),
        ],
      },
    },
  ];
  if (preProcessor) {
    loaders.push(require.resolve(preProcessor));
  }
  return loaders;
};
```

Its the base one after I eject the app.
Also, I added the postcss.config.js to my root directory but I don't know where to import it.

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('autoprefixer')
    ],
};
```

Anyone has any tips on how to proceed to make autoprefixer work with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRA uses autoprefixer out of the box

Comment: I get no -ms-;-webkit-; -o- prefixes anywhere in my css :/ neither on inspected elements in edge, ie, firefox or chrome. Maybe its because I ejected the app, and then my css is not location in one css file, but in multiple little files imported on the pages that they affect (i.e: `page1.js` has a line `import './page1.css'`)

Comment: Could you give me an example of a property where you expect the prefix?
Here is default browser list in CRA config
`"browserslist": {
    "development": [
      "last 2 chrome versions",
      "last 2 firefox versions",
      "last 2 edge versions"
    ],
    "production": [
      ">0.25%",
      "not op_mini all",
      "ie 11"
    ]
  }`

Comment: Of course :) here is my browserlist:
`"browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie < 10",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]` I have to make the website compatible with I.E. 10 and up. I use `display: flex` quite often and I know that autoprefixer would make it into: `display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;` but it doesnt

Comment: Try `[">0.2%","not dead","ie >= 10", "not op_mini all"]`. Here you can check your config https://browserl.ist/

Comment: didnt affect the result, ill try building the project and seeing if that changes anything

Comment: Did you change the settings in `development` or in `production` key?

Comment: Ouf ok! So i changed it to your suggestion, then ran `npm run build` script and then `serve -s build`, and it finally worked! You're a christmas miracle Mateusz! I changed the browserlists in the package.json file ^_^ Thank you, so very much

Comment: I'm happy to hear that :)